# Cannot call chrome.alarms.create() from a content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension right now.

My problem is that when I call `chrome.alarms.create()`, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
```

I have these files in my extension package:

**manifest.json**

```
{   
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Tool",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": ["background", "tabs", "webNavigation", "alarms"]
}
```

**myscript.js**

```
chrome.alarms.create("aaa", {"when":Date.now()+5000});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm){
  console.log("hello");
});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "myscript.js"});
});
```

When I call `chrome.alarms.create()` in `background.js`, it works fine.
But, when I call the function in `myscript.js`, it causes the error.

What is the cause and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access most Chrome APIs from a content script. You will need to use the Messaging API to send a message to the background page which can then call the Alarms API.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: Yep, also consider checking out [chromeps](https://github.com/andersp/chromeps) to help simplify message passing.